# Is RxJava support for Room the same as RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

There is now a [RxJava support library for Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), and so I was wondering if I can remove [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) library from my Android project, or use both together? I noticed that the Room support version has the same functionalities as RxJava (I am just using it for accessing a local database).

Comment: Room has an optional RxJava2 module.

Comment: Link? so there's no need to use the standalone rxjava2 right?

Comment: "RxJava support for Room" does not mean Room is equipped with RxJava. It just means that it is compatible with RxJava. You still need RxJava library if you want to use it with Room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `room-rxjava2` library has [RxRoom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RxRoom) which in turn depends on the components from rxjava2 library. Therefore build will fail in the case of excluding `rxjava2` library from the project dependencies.